# asmak packet listener and custom IQProvider not triggering / called

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm using asmack the latest version (asmack-android-8-source-0.8.3) in a android project and I'm trying to communicate with the server by sending multiple IQs and receiving responses.
I receive the response and it's parsed correctly but the package listener it's not triggering.
I have the following code:

vCard_IQProvider.java

```
public class vCard_IQProvider implements IQProvider
{
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "vcard-temp";
    public static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "vCard";
    public static final String LAST_STATUS = "LAST_STATUS";
    public static final String LAST_STATUS_DESCRIPTION = "LAST_STATUS_DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String WORK_TIME_RANGE = "WORK_TIME_RANGE";
    public static final String SOUND_SETTINGS = "SOUND_SETTINGS";
    public static final String AUTO_LOCATION_MACHINE_DATA = "AUTO_LOCATION_MACHINE_DATA";
    public static final String AUTO_LOCATION = "AUTO_LOCATION";
    public static final String AUTO_LOCATION_ENABLED = "AUTO_LOCATION_ENABLED";
    public static final String AUTO_ONLINE = "AUTO_ONLINE";
    public static final String HIDEACTIONNOTIFICATIONS = "HideActionNotifications";
    public static final String AUTO_CONNECT = "AUTO_CONNECT";
    public static final String AUTO_OFFLINE_WORK_TIME = "AUTO_OFFLINE_WORK_TIME";
    public static final String AUTO_RELOGIN = "AUTO_RELOGIN";
    public static final String CONNECTED_VIA_INTERNET = "CONNECTED_VIA_INTERNET";
    public static final String MINIMIZE_CHAT = "MINIMIZE_CHAT";
    public static final String PROMPT_PROJECT_SWITCH = "PROMPT_PROJECT_SWITCH";
    public static final String MACHINE_NAME = "MACHINE_NAME";
    public static final String MROFFICE_VER = "MROFFICE_VER";
    public static final String WORK = "WORK";
    public static final String LOCALITY = "LOCALITY";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String REGION = "REGION";
    public static final String EXT = "EXT";
    public static final String LAST_ACTIVITY_TS = "LAST_ACTIVITY_TS";
    public static final String FUTURE_STATUS = "FUTURE_STATUS";
    public static final String FUTURE_STATUS_DESCRIPTION = "FUTURE_STATUS_DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String FUTURE_STATUS_TS = "FUTURE_STATUS_TS";
    public static final String CUSTOM = "CUSTOM";
    public static final String PREF = "PREF";
    private Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception
    {
        String name;
        boolean isEmpty;
        boolean done = false;

        while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && false == done)
        {
            name = parser.getName();

            switch (parser.getEventType())
            {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                {
                    isEmpty = parser.isEmptyElementTag();

                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(LAST_STATUS) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(LAST_STATUS, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(LAST_STATUS_DESCRIPTION) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(LAST_STATUS_DESCRIPTION , parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(WORK_TIME_RANGE) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(WORK_TIME_RANGE, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(SOUND_SETTINGS) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(SOUND_SETTINGS, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTO_LOCATION_MACHINE_DATA) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(AUTO_LOCATION_MACHINE_DATA, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTO_LOCATION) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(AUTO_LOCATION, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTO_LOCATION_ENABLED) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(AUTO_LOCATION_ENABLED, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTO_ONLINE) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(AUTO_ONLINE, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(HIDEACTIONNOTIFICATIONS) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(HIDEACTIONNOTIFICATIONS, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTO_CONNECT) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(AUTO_CONNECT, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTO_OFFLINE_WORK_TIME) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(AUTO_OFFLINE_WORK_TIME, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTO_RELOGIN) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(AUTO_RELOGIN, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(CONNECTED_VIA_INTERNET) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(CONNECTED_VIA_INTERNET, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(MINIMIZE_CHAT) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(MINIMIZE_CHAT, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(PROMPT_PROJECT_SWITCH) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(PROMPT_PROJECT_SWITCH, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(MACHINE_NAME) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(MACHINE_NAME, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(MROFFICE_VER) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(MROFFICE_VER, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(WORK) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(WORK, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(LOCALITY) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(LOCALITY, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(TIMESTAMP) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(TIMESTAMP, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(REGION) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(REGION, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(EXT) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(EXT, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(LAST_ACTIVITY_TS) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(LAST_ACTIVITY_TS, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(FUTURE_STATUS) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(FUTURE_STATUS, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(FUTURE_STATUS_DESCRIPTION) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(FUTURE_STATUS_DESCRIPTION, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(FUTURE_STATUS_TS) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(FUTURE_STATUS_TS, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(CUSTOM) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(CUSTOM, parser.nextText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(PREF) && false == isEmpty)
                    {
                        list.put(PREF, parser.nextText());
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                {
                    done = ELEMENT_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        name = null;

        return new vCard_IQ(list);
    }
}
```

vCard_IQ.java

```
public class vCard_IQ extends IQ
{
    public static final String ID = "vcard";
    private static Map<String, String> list;
    private static boolean finishedParsing = false;

    public vCard_IQ(Map<String, String> l)
    {
        if(null == list)
        {
            list  = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }

        list.clear();
        list.putAll(l);

        finishedParsing = true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getChildElementXML()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static final Map<String, String> getData()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public static void setFinishedParsingToFalse()
    {
        finishedParsing = false;
    }

    public static final boolean finishedParsing()
    {
        return finishedParsing;
    }
}
```

I add the provider:

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider(vCard_IQProvider.ELEMENT_NAME, vCard_IQProvider.NAMESPACE, new vCard_IQProvider());
```

and the package listener:

```
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener()
{
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet p)
    {   
        if(p.getPacketID().equals(vCard_IQ.ID))
        {
            vCard_IQ pp = (vCard_IQ)p;

            //access the parsed data
            //vCard_IQ.getData().get.......

            pp = null;
        }
    }
}, 
    new PacketFilter()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Packet arg0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The packet filter is set to accept all packets, the listner is not triggering for some reason. I can see in the debugger that the server is sending the responses.

I even tried to bypass the listener by creating an asynk task an waiting in the background thread until the response is parsed and than I access it. Now it works only for the first iq sent - I receive a response and it's parsed correctly, but for the rest I can see in the debugger that the server it's sending responses but it never reaches the parser. The parser it's never called.

```
   Asynk<Void, Void, Void> asynk = new Asynk<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        Packet iq_vcard;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            for(String s : names_list)
            {
                    final String name = s;
                    iq_vcard = new Packet()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public String toXML()
                        {
                            String str = String.format("<iq from='%s' to='%s' type='get' id='" + vCard_IQ.ID + "'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq>",
                                            sharedPrefs.getString(LogIn.USERNAME, "") + "@" + sharedPrefs.getString(Settings_LogIn.DOMAIN, Settings_LogIn.ERROR) + "/iOffice",
                                            name + "@" + sharedPrefs.getString(Settings_LogIn.DOMAIN, Settings_LogIn.ERROR));

                            Log.e("iq_vcard", str);
                            return str;
                        }
                    };
                    connection().sendPacket(iq_vcard);
                    iq_vcard = null;

                    while(false == vCard_IQ.finishedParsing())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            Log.e("TAG", "waiting to finish parsing...");
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    //access the parsed data
                    //vCard_IQ.getData().get.......

                    vCard_IQ.setFinishedParsingToFalse();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {

        }
    };
    asynk.execute();
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm correct or not, but what I observed in my application, when u start your IQ provider, then no other packet listener works. All kind of outgoing or incoming packets are handled by IQ provider only. Try to log all packets in IQ provider, then u'll come to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in aSmack and after numerous attempts at fixing this issue, failed attempts of compiling aSmack myself following this [tutorial](http://overwatering.org/blog/2013/05/compiling-asmack/) and trying anything that I could think of, I did the following: I created a new package in my android project and dumped all of the aSmack's java classes there. This way I let eclipse compile aSmack and I got a better control over it's code.

The problem was that every time I would receive an custom iq response from server, in PacketParserUtils.java aSmack would return a wrong elementName and namespace, thus choosing a wrong iq provider to parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: 
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/provider/IQProvider.html

> At the end of the method call, the parser **must** be positioned on
>   the closing tag of the child element.

Answer (score 0):

Just if somebody is trying to do the same, I found what was the problem.

The while condition on the `vCard_IQProvider` class is wrong, it should be:

```
while(!done && parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
```

Otherwise when done is set to true, the while will check again the condition and move the parser to the next element (with the call `parser.next()`).